# Counter Example: If |f| is Riemann integrable, then f is not necessarily integrable

Tags: examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

I know that if |f| is Riemann integrable, then f is not necessarily integrable, but I am having difficulty in finding a counterexample. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\-1&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

For example when $f(x)=-1$ for all rational values of $x,$ and $f(x)=1$ for all irrational values of $x$  on $[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks ! But then how do you show that f is not integrable, using U(f,P)-L(f,P) < ε please? I know that the upper sum is equal to 1 and the lower sum is -1, and U(f,P)-L(f,P)=2, but I do not know how I can show that this is smaller than ε.

Comment: @CXB Because it is not smaller! As you said,

$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=2>\varepsilon
$$
for any $\varepsilon < 2.$ This implies that $f$ is NOT integrable.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot :)